# FileMaker TimeStamp field UPDATE using SQL

Tags: sql, filemaker

I need to update a FileMaker Timestamp field with a timestamp taken from PHP and put into a script using the PHP API and executeSQL API and plugin

so

```
UPDATE table SET time ='2011-05-27 11:28:57'
```

My Question is as follows, how do I utilise the available scripting functions within Filemaker Pro 11 to convert the string that is being supplied within the SQL statement to an acceptable TimeStamp format for FileMake? or is it possible using the executeSQL plugin for FileMaker to do the conversion within the ExecuteSQL() function within the Execute SQL plugin?

Comment: yes it reports "error" which is of course really useful lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it out, but it should work using CAST:

```
CAST( expression AS type [ (length) ] )
```

so, it should read:

```
UPDATE table SET time = CAST ('2011-05-27 11:28:57' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

However, please be aware that Filemaker's own ExecuteSQL() functions doesn't support UPDATE or INSERT INTO statements. You need to get a free extension from Dracoventions called epSQLExecute() in order to do this.

Hope this helps (someone).

Gary

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much to go on, but my guess would be that you are updating a timestamp column with a string that does not match the required format.

You should convert your string to the appropriate object and then the update should work.

Comment: OO Have the answer its not that bad really you add a TIMESTAMP before the string and ExecuteSQL does the rest